# Having query to compare

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need compare the sum of one column, this could be less or equal than other value in other table. So I have this, but I don't know how make the sintax

```
SELECT sembrado.f_AreaSiembra, tenencia.f_AreaDedicadaCultivos
  FROM Clt_Sembrado as sembrado
  INNER JOIN Fnc_TenenciaUsoTierra as tenencia ON sembrado.c_Fk_IdBoleta = tenencia.c_Fk_IdBoleta
  HAVING (SUM(sembrado.f_AreaSiembra) <= tenencia.f_AreaDedicadaCultivos)  AND (sembrado.c_Fk_IdBoleta = 45550711 AND tenencia.c_Fk_IdBoleta = 45550711)
```

How can I do this??

thanks

Comment: What do you want: the SUM of AreaSiembra to be less than the Sum of AreaDedicadaCultivos or less than the maximum?
Or maybe you want the sum of all rows where AreaSiembra <= AreaDedicadaCultivos ?

Comment: I need the SUM of AreaSiembra to be less or equal that the field AreaDedicadaCultivos  and the c_Fk_IdBoleta = 45550711

Comment: Ah, so you only have one row in Fnc_TenenciaUsoTierra with c_Fk_IdBoleta = 45550711. Editting my answer below right now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you just want the conditions in the where clause: you can still use WHERE within the aggregated.

```
SELECT
   SUM(sembrado.f_AreaSiembra) as SummedArea,
   (SELECT SUM(f_AreaDedicadaCultivos)
      FROM Fnc_TenenciaUsoTierra
      WHERE c_Fk_IdBoleta = sembrado.c_Fk_IdBoleta)
   AS AreaDedicadaCultivos
FROM
   Clt_Sembrado as sembrado
WHERE
   sembrado.c_Fk_IdBoleta = 45550711
GROUP BY sembrado.c_Fk_IdBoleta
HAVING SUM(sembrado.f_AreaSiembra) <= (SELECT SUM(f_AreaDedicadaCultivos)
      FROM Fnc_TenenciaUsoTierra
      WHERE c_Fk_IdBoleta = sembrado.c_Fk_IdBoleta)
```

I haven't tested, so might be small syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will generate the right output, but in general, when you do `HAVING` you have to have a `GROUP BY`, so your query should be like this:

```
SELECT     sembrado.f_AreaSiembra, tenencia.f_AreaDedicadaCultivos
FROM         Clt_Sembrado as sembrado INNER JOIN
             Fnc_TenenciaUsoTierra as tenencia ON sembrado.c_Fk_IdBoleta = tenencia.c_Fk_IdBoleta
group by sembrado.f_AreaSiembra,tenencia.f_AreaDedicadaCultivos
HAVING (SUM(sembrado.f_AreaSiembra) <= tenencia.f_AreaDedicadaCultivos)  AND (sembrado.c_Fk_IdBoleta = 45550711 AND tenencia.c_Fk_IdBoleta = 45550711)
```

Comment: yes, but send this error: Column 'Clt_Sembrado.c_Fk_IdBoleta' in the HAVING clause is invalid because it is not contained in an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Column 'Fnc_TenenciaUsoTierra.c_Fk_IdBoleta' in the HAVING clause is invalid because it is not contained in an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @ale, it's telling you what the problem is. You need to add `Clt_Sembrado.c_Fk_IdBoleta` to the `GROUP BY` too. Ex: `group by sembrado.f_AreaSiembra,tenencia.f_AreaDedicadaCultivos,Clt_Sembrado.c_Fk_IdBoleta`

Answer (score 0):

Syntactically, you could use something like this:

```
SELECT t1.A, SUM(t1.C), SUM(t2.D)
FROM table t1
JOIN table t2 ON t1.A = t2.A
GROUP BY t1.A                // or group-by any other column that is applicable to the schema
HAVING (SUM(t1.C) <= SUM(t2.D))
```

Now, fit this (tables and columns) into your schema, since the above should give you an idea on what's the syntax to perform such a task.